# WordPress page broken image paths

Tags: wordpress, image, path, server

I made a WP page a while ago (not for me) and all of a sudden most images can't be displayed ...

I took a look into html code and saw that the img paths are all wrong!

Those workig look like: http://www.niebauer.co.at/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/senato-tasse-178x108px.jpg

The ones that DO NOT work: /usr/local/www/apache22/data/niebauer/www.niebauer.co.at/htdocs/wp/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/cool-2015-9941_165x184.jpg

I have NO idea why WP all of a sudden changed those paths. I tried to REUPLOAD some images but it seems, wp does this automatically "wrong". The only working solution I found was to upload them in the EXACT size they will display on the page. So I guess something is wrong with the WP asset manager but I did not change anything.

Comment: Check your browser console. There are two images which give 404 error. Probably they are not present in http://www.niebauer.co.at/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/  folder.

Try disabling plugins if any to check if there are any conflicts that are causing the issue.